# Regex to match the number that resides in square brackets as a part of parsing for my Sumo Logic query

Tags: regex

I am beginner in Regular Expression. I am working on a problem where need to match the number that resides in square brackets as a part of parsing for my Sumo Logic query. I need to match just the number '45678'. 
 `2017-08-24 08:55:36,659 INFO  [CompanyServiceImpl:XXX] Getting isEducation  for company id [45678]`

I tried it with above example but it did not work. I came up with `[^\[]\d+[^\]]` but this solution matches the other numbers in the string such as timestamp.

Above is just an example. There are different id's in square brackets in multiple logs.I need to match all. Not specific to the 45678. I would appreciate if anybody help me with that.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what the input string is. Could you clarify by adding it in explicit codeblocks?

Comment: Updated my question as you said.

Answer (score 1):

**If using capturing group**

Well, use `\[(\d+)\]` the number contained is now in the first capturing group

**else**

```
(?<=\[)\d+(?=\])
```

See [demo on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/3Ju58s/1)

Comment: `\[(\d+)\]` is matching the square brackets too. I don't need to match brackets.

Comment: You cannot use capturing group?

Comment: I don't understand,  are you asking or telling?

Comment: Asking, using capturing groups is way easier (less  worthless work around in the regex)

Comment: Edited my answer to include both

Comment: Using the match is good if you only need a single value, when you need more (or not) use capturing groups instead.

Comment: Could you please show some examples for  capturing groups?

Comment: How you grab the content of those capturing groups depends on the language you're using.

Comment: Thanks, I am actually working on Sumo Logic query where i parse the logs using regex like `| parse regex "(?:id |id :|root_id :) (?<company_id>\d+)" nodrop`
e.g. i have logs like

 `Calling service for id : 17030
Getting object  for  root_id [17030]
Successfully completed for root_id : 17030`

Comment: Thanks @Vivick . It worked for me. It was little different in Sumo logic. But i got it. I appreciate for your time and help.

Answer (score 0):

`(?<=\[)\d+(?=\])`

This captures 1 or more digits between brackets.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/8dlV0K/2)

Comment: `\[\d+\]` gives the same match as `\[(\d+)\]`

Comment: Edit made so that it doesn't capture the brackets.

Comment: trying to use this in my query

Comment: Thank you very much. I appreciate for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can use positive lookaheads for that.

`\d+(?=\])`

You can also test out your regex here: http://regexr.com/. Very useful resource IMO.